# Формат объявления функции

Tags: python, функции

Во время дебагинга кода в Django наткнулся на это в tests.py:

```
def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
    return super().setUpTestData()
```

Я раньше такого не видел. Можете объяснить мне что это означает в функции:

```
def setUpTestData(cls) -> None:
```

то есть, эта стрелка. Я видел такое и с `str`:

```
-> None
```

Comment: Какой-то странный код, зачем там return, если мы typehint на  None объявили.

Answer (score 1):

это typehint. Подсказка о том, какой тип данных возвращает данный метод.
Тут подробней можно почитать https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html